# How can I use "open implemenation" shortcut on "unconnected" projects?

Tags: eclipse, ibm-rad

I have a few projects in RAD 8.0, let's say DAOProject, EJBProject, WebProject, standard stuff. Now, they aren't "connected" in the usual way (meaning change in DAOProject won't automatically cause change in other projects) until I do an Ant "publish/resolve", meaning that EJBProject has DAOProject as an "imported" jar. Is there a way to setup RAD so when I choose "open implementation" on an interface, it opens the source file from another project? Currently, when I choose "open declaration" it opens a decompiled class file of the interface (good), but when I choose "open implementation", it opens a source file from the same project which implements the interface (bad, the file is a test unit file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can only send you to something in the file's project's Java Build Path.